# How to select the information from a specific time? I'm using phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08qhP.png)

The datatype of DATEInvoice is VARCHAR

From the image above, if I want to select the information of the invoice from specific time let say from 1-12-2020 00:00:00 to 13-12-2020 23:59:00, how can I write? I have try many ways to write. For example,

`SELECT * FROM INVOICE WHERE DATEINVOICE BETWEEN To_date('01-12-2020 00:00:00','dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') AND  To_date('13-12-2020 23:59:00','dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS')`

**BUT THE RESULT I GET IS RETURN ZERO ROWS. Hope anyone can help me, I am having trouble on this.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Fix the data model so values are stored using the correct type!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simplify your logic to:

```
WHERE DATEINVOICE >= '2020-01-12' AND
      DATEINVOICE < '2020-01-14'
```

In some databases, you should identify date constants with the (standard) `DATE` keyword:

```
WHERE DATEINVOICE >= DATE '2020-01-12' AND
      DATEINVOICE < DATE '2020-01-14'
```

This assumes that `DATEINVOICE` is stored as a valid datetime/timestamp value in your database.  If it is a string, then it has the wrong type.  You should fix your data model.  If someone else has created such a broken data model, then you can convert the value in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE TO_DATE(DATEINVOICE, 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') >= '2020-01-12' AND
      TO_DATE(DATEINVOICE, 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') < '2020-01-14'
```

However, the effort should really be on fixing the data model.

Comment: because the value in the `DATEINVOICE` is inserted from c++.(I'm doing a project so it must be VARCHAR).My question is how to select * from a specific time. CLICK THE LINK TO SEE THE IMAGE

Comment: still got error, it said FUNCTION TO_DATE does not exist

Comment: @watashiwachooi . . . You should be using a *parameter* not munging the query string.  That is really the ultimate problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can use Please try MySQL's DATE() function:

```
WHERE DATE(datetime) = '2009-10-20'
```

You could also try this:

```
WHERE datetime LIKE '2009-10-20%'
```

Comment: I want a specific date to date, not just single date

Comment: can you please try Date() function